# Classifying abelian groups or prime exponent without using the classification of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let p be a prime. Without using the classification of finite abelian groups, classify (up to isomorphism) all finite abelian groups with every non-identity element having order p. (Note that when p=2 this gives a classification of all finite groups with every non-identity element having order 2, since every such group is automatically abelian.)

One theorem I suspect can be helpful is the following:

Every group of order $p^2$, where p is prime, is isomorphic to $Z_{p^2}$ or $Z_p \oplus Z_p$

This has a corollary that states:

If G is a group of order $p^2$, where p is a prime, then G is abelian

I think those could both be helpful but I'm still quite fuzzy on how to classify groups. I don't really understand that concept

Comment: The first is potentially relevant, if looking at the proof might help you generlaize. The second is useless, since you are being asked to describe **abelian** groups, you may assume your group is abelian to begin with. A theorem that tells you a group must be abelian just tells you what you are already assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

1. First, prove that an Abelian group with each non-identity element of order $p$
   can be considered as a vector space over a field of $p$ elements $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
2. Then use the theorem from linear algebra that
   two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

Comment: I feel like this is just a teeny bit more complicated than necessary. If you prove $1$ then you have that every finite abelian group satisfying the aforementioned property is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ for some $n$. Then you're done.